# How to share an instance between multiple applications (web or ejb) running in the same JVM?

Tags: java

I have to design a way to be able to share the same object between multiple applications. All applications will be on same JVM. They can be different war sides or jar sides. The problem that I am trying to fix is as follows.
I have a jar side and in a web application, i create stubs to be used in the war side for ejb invocations. I have another application and want to be able to use to inspect the same object (which is being referenced by the first web app using stubs). Is there a way to achieve this.

Amogh.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue once that took a week to debug, it ended up being a classpath issue. When you are building your app, you will need to create a jar that will hold the classes that you want to share between apps.

So you would end up building the 3 ( or N ) projects in the following order:

shared.jar

And then put the shared.jar on the path of the other war and ear files when you compile.

app.war
ejb.jar
app.ear
etc...